# Apache Rewrite rule doesn't work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/cat/(.*)/ index.php?cat=$1

</IfModule>
```

But this rule doesn't work.
I have this url `/index.php?cat=auto%20loan` and I want to change to `/cat/auto-loan/`.

So if you have any idea then please let me know.

Comment: You might need a slash: `/index.php?cat=$1`

Comment: am not sure but `.*` might be a little too permissive. try something like `RewriteRule ^index/cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1`

Comment: @DusanBajic I have tried your suggestions but doesn't work.

Comment: `RewriteRule index/cat/(.*)/ index.php?cat=$1` rewrites a request from `http://example.com/index/cat/foobar` to `http://example.com/index.php?cat=foobar` . Change  your Rewrite pattern to `^cat/(.*)$` if you want `/cat/auto-loan` .

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

I have made forward slash at the end optional. You should not make it optional to avoid duplicate content issue(SEO) such as `RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1` or `RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/$ index.php?cat=$1`. Choose a format and stick to it.

Comment: If you have example.com/.htaccess, any request  to example.com/anything needs to read .htaccess file. I have removed the index part in your rewrite rule. Adding ` /index ` is not a good practice. So the link that looks like example.com/cat/auto-loan should work depending on the format you have chosen (with slash or without slash). If you want both links to be accessible, you may need to 301 redirect one link to the other only to remove duplicate content issue for search engines.